# R error in evaluating the argument. Arguments imply differing number of rows

Tags: r, excel, lm

I've tried to research the answer and I've found something close to my error but not similar enough to help me. My code is as follows:

```
setwd("Directory")
require(XLConnect)
wb <- loadWorkbook("workbook.xlsx")
st = readWorksheet(wb, sheet = getSheets(wb))

summary(lm(X36~Temp.C., data=st))
```

Where X36 is a column within the Excel file.

The error I'm getting is:

```
"Error in summary(lm(X36 ~ Temp.C., data = st)) : 
 error in evaluating the argument 'object' in selecting a method for 
function 'summary': Error in data.frame(Info = list(Trial.. = c("Purpose: ", 
"Cure: ", "Cond: ",  : 
 arguments imply differing number of rows: 12, 0, 7, 5, 10, 17, 3, 500, 25, 31, 8"
```

What I'm trying to do is create a data frame so I can run a `lm` on different columns. I believe the problem might be there being different sheets of differing amounts of rows within them but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try one sheet at a time:

```
 st <- readWorksheet(wb, sheet = "mtcars")
```

where mtcars is the name of a sheet in "wb" workbook.

or try:

```
st <- readTable(wb, sheet = "mtcars_sheet", table = "MtcarsTable")
```

if you know the sheet name and table name.

Answer (score 0):

Input the data into R as a csv file type and then you should be able to do what you want so much easier

```
data<-read.csv("workbook.csv")
```

this way you can treat your data like a matrix :)

Comment: That works but the way the Excel files are on the server, they're .xlsx and I have to leave them that way so they can still be edited by other people. I was making them csv but I had to do that one at a time and we have hundreds of files

Comment: ah ok i wasnt sure what your data was like :)